# How to place dynamic content in xslt in Umbraco 4.11.9

Tags: c#, umbraco

I am new in Umbraco.Currently I am working on my new project in which I have Umbraco 4.11.9.I am fetching data from Dynamic CRM and want to display on Umbraco website

now my question is how can I place this content using Xlst file? my old developer use xslt for desingning and render static content.

also is there any other way to not use xslt and still I can render content.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can extend xslt with some custom functions that fetch the data for you (http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/xslt/extend-your-xslt-with-custom-functions)

2) Instead of using xslt macros you can use razor macros, which will allow you to write c# code directly in the macro. (http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/templating/macros/razor/).

3) Other than that you could still use either razor or xslt and fetch the data with javascript and ajax.

I would propose to use razor macros, but only if creating new macros, as that would require a total rewrite of the macro, and only ajax as the last way out, unless its dynamic in such way it would make sense.